# Trigger not working on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create to trigger to divide my primary key into two groups.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `q_locations` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 `standalone` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `standalone` (`standalone`)
)
```

If standalone is 0, id should start from 1, if standalone = 1, id should start from 1000. Id should be increment after each insert.

My trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_q_locations
BEFORE INSERT ON q_locations
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET New.id = (
    SELECT coalesce(max(id) + 1, (case when standalone = 0 then 1 else 1000 end))  
    FROM q_locations 
    WHERE standalone = NEW.standalone);
END;
```

Update: So with help I got, I managed to insert trigger without no errors, bu when I update my locations table, trigger doesn't do anything. Values just keep incrementing as default.

Comment: `SELECT coalesce(max(id) + 1...)` is not going to work correctly in an environment where you have concurrent inserts and deletes on `q_locations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SET NEW.id = (SELECT coalesce(...) ...)
```

Maybe SELECT INTO isn't working properly in Update Triggers with NEW-Aliases.

UPDATE:

This should work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_q_locations
BEFORE INSERT ON q_locations
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE currentid INT;
  SET currentid = (SELECT max(id) FROM q_locations WHERE standalone = NEW.standalone);

  IF NEW.standalone = 0 THEN 
    SET NEW.id = coalesce(currentid + 1, 1);
  ELSE 
    SET NEW.id = coalesce(currentid + 1,1000);
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed trigger, ant its included in database with no errors, but not working at all.

Comment: coalesce() returns the first not null element from given parameters. This means max(id) + 1 is always returned.
Try this:
`IF standalone = 0 THEN
    SET NEW.id max(id) + 1
ELSE
    SET NEW.id = max(id) + 1000`

Comment: You mean change it to: BEGIN
    IF standalone = 0 THEN SET NEW.id max(id) + 1 ELSE SET NEW.id = max(id) + 1000
END ?